# Adding a window or dialog box dynamically?

Tags: java, android

i want to create a small message box that pops up every time the user presses a certain button. Is there any way for me to display a simple message box every time a button is pressed? Here is my code. I made a function that draws the dialog box using the information passed in from the click method:

```
        inventoryList.setClickable(true);
    inventoryList
            .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int position, long arg3) {
                    localFile file = (localFile) inventoryList
                            .getItemAtPosition(position);
                    showItem(file);
                }
            });
}

public void showItem(localFile file) {
    TextView wpnName = (TextView) weaponDialog.findViewById(R.id.itemName);
    TextView wpnDmg = (TextView) weaponDialog.findViewById(R.id.wpnDamage);
    TextView wpnWei = (TextView) weaponDialog.findViewById(R.id.wpnWeightA);
    TextView wpnRar = (TextView) weaponDialog.findViewById(R.id.wpnRarity);
    wpnName.setText(file.name);
    String sizeStr = String.valueOf(file.size);
    wpnDmg.setText(sizeStr);
    wpnWei.setText(sizeStr);
    weaponDialog.show();
}
```

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: There are countless tutorials on this. show some effort. Search for clicking buttons java, and then popup window java and combine the two

Comment: And the specifics of a solution will depend on the specifics of your problem that you will want to delineate for us: what GUI library? Will the GUI have focus, or are you looking for a system wide hot-key?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Button yourButton= (Button) findViewById(R.id.yourbuttonId); // your created button

     //what happens when touching the specific Button

    yourButton.setOnClickListener(new view.OnClickListener() { 


    @Override

    public void onClick(View v) {

    Dialog obj = new Dialog (this);   // Define New Dialog Named obj

    obj.setTitle("your dialog title)");  //Naming The Dialog title

    TextView tv = new TextView (this); // Creating TextView object to use it inside the Dialog 

    tv.setText("your Text to be shown in the Dialog"); // Setting the TextView Text 

    obj.setContentView(tv); // setting the TextView Content inside your Dialog

    obj.show(); // Method to show the dialog 

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```

Here is The Code Hope I helped a Little bit :)

Answer (score 0):

These tutorial may help you

http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Swing-Tutorial/Swing-Tutorial-JOptionPane.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html

and also here is a example program

http://java.about.com/od/UsingDialogBoxes/ss/Simple-Message-Dialog-Boxes-Program.htm